# When can sublinear growth imply concavity?

Tags: convexity

Consider a function $f(x,\lambda):\mathbb{R}^{2}_{+}\to\mathbb{R}_{+}$ that is uniformly continuous, smooth, lower bounded and convex. Let

$\qquad g(\lambda)=\inf_{x}\;f(x,\lambda)$

We know that $g(0)=0$,  $g^{'}(\lambda)>0$, and  $g(a\lambda)<ag(\lambda), \forall a>1$. Can we conclude that $g$ is also concave?